# Integration Tests could not load file or assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, integration-testing

I keep on encountering issues with my xunit integration tests.

The Integration Test project is set to target .NET 4.6.1.

The Integration Test project has a reference to ASP.NET Core (targetting net461) project A.

Project A has a reference to a .NET Standard Library which uses `System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates, Version=4.1.0.0`, let's call it Project B.

When creating a TestServer from my Integration Test project, the test fails with

```
Message: System.IO.FileLoadException : Could not load file or assembly 'System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040).
```

However, when running project A alone, it itself does not need to have a reference to `System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates`.  I'm assuming this is because project B already has this reference.

How do I go about ensuring that my integration test project is able to resolve all of its dependencies from downstream projects?

Comment: So project A is a aspnet core project, and it has a reference of Project B which uses System.Security...? If so, Project A has an indirect reference to dotnet standard because itself reference project B.

Comment: @jpgrassi Strange thing, I convert my unit test project to xUnit .NET Core, and targetted net461.  All my indirect references just started working, without any issues.

Comment: Are you targeting the full framework? Now I`m confused.

Comment: @jpgrassi I have .NET Core projects that target the full framework because of some dependencies.